# Which is the best way to do the following task in java

Tags: java, static, heap-memory

I have more than 20 commonly used methods in my application. I would like to move that 20 methods into a common class.

Here my doubt is, define all the methods are static or normal method and create a global object to access that normal methods.

```
class Common {

public String method1() {........}
public String method2() {........}
public String method3() {........}
public String method4() {........}
public String method5() {........}
...

}
```

Creating object.

```
class CommonService {
    private static Common common;

    public static Common getCommon() {
    if(null == common) {
    common = new common();
    }
    return common;
    }
}
```

If we create all the methods using static means, all 20 methods are stored in PermGen section of the heap.

But if we follow above method means, only one object can be created and stored in java heap.

Please clarify which one is the best way.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve ? Everything have its own Pros-Cons in every field. Better You can make it as a `final`  `Util` class  and make method `static`.

Comment: are the methods related in any way? why would this be better than a constructor? (or a singleton, if you want them all on the same instance)

Comment: I'm not sure about `static` methods, but from a testability point of view, singletons are frowned upon

Comment: If you don't have to share state between that methods, you should be fine with static methods.

Comment: @subodh joshi: What exactly you want to achieve ? >>> Application Performance and memory management. So why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we create all the methods using static means, all 20 methods are stored in PermGen section of the heap.

Methods are not data, but code. Where code is stored does not depend on whether a method accepts an implicit `this` parameter or not.  If you use the singleton approach, method code will still occupy storage and additionally there will be an instance on the heap.

However, all of the above is irrelevant and you are focusing on a completely wrong aspect of your design. What matters is how the decision will affect the code which uses these methods:

- static methods are simple and a great choice for pure functions (which don't depend on any external state);
- singletons allow polymorphism, therefore make the methods easier to mock for testing.

Comment: As per memory management point of view and performance vice, which one is correct approach?

Comment: There is essentially no difference from the memory management point of view. The only difference are the 16 bytes allocated for a single object on the heap.

Comment: I am new in java, so please accept my chilly questions and give me your valuable answer. Actually from my knowledge, i can understand jvm allocate memory space for each static variables and methods in PermGen space. So if we create methods using static, jvm create 20memory space in PermGen space. But if we use singleton, only one memory space will create in permgen. This is my doubt. I am correct or not?

Comment: @Anbazhagan optimization of 10-20 bytes and general problems with good design of code, packages... is bad

Comment: Remember that the storage for a class's methods is completely independent of instances of that class. A method is stored only once, regardless how many instances you have. That's why it's irrelevant whether the method is static or not. _Variables_ are another thing because they are data. A static variable's storage is different from an instance variable's. But this is not relevant to your design dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

"Common functions" is not quite accurate. It really depends on what you want to do, for example when I make some string utils I make StringUtils class and it has what I need. Whether to make it static or not depends on data to be processed, if one information might be used more than once for a call then answer is simple - use instances.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about the "best" way in terms of design.

If the methods are used for general purposes, making them `static` is preferable, as you won't have any state to store and you'll *save memory* this way.

You should consider other things before deciding if you want to use `static` methods in your utility class or not. On one hand the utility class will be very easy to test, and it's highly accessible. On the other hand, it's very hard to mock `static` methods in your test.

If I have a utility class, I would write it as follows:

```
public final class Common {

    private Common() { }

    public static int method1() { }
    public static int method2() { }
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the methods do.

If those methods are just helper methods, that do not alter state then `static` is probably better because that way you do not have to create an object every time you want to use one of the methods. You can just call `Common.method()`

However, if the object has state then you should rater use object methods and create a new object when you want to use the methods.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If sense of this method is "execute pure function" like mathematical sin(x), cos(x) etc static method is the best.

They belongs to one domain? (range of themats) or to different? (then create more "utility classes" with correct name)

If have state (like many people say) maybe better is singleton.

Shape of the question "i have 20 method in application" and name Common suggest previous (older) design problem, I say "procedural thinking", poor vision of OOP.

Hard to say without code.